# Orientation of Switch in Android

Tags: android, switch-statement, orientation

Can I change the orientation of a Switch View in android..?[example of a switch view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvsTH.png) i.e. make it vertical or horizontal.

Comment: Use the android:rotate="-90" or android:rotate="90".  If you want text next to it, then just nest the switch with a textview in some parent view.

Comment: Fyi if you have a text it's going to be rotated too. I think this is not the desired solution

Comment: Separating the text isn't that hard.

Comment: okay. I will try the android:rotate, and see what is comes up with. ..

Comment: I don't want text btw.

Answer (score -1):

No, it doesn't have such a setting, but it can be rotated as with any component:

```
switch.setRotation(float)

<Switch ...
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:rotation="270" />
```

Comment: I should write this inside my xml file ..?

Comment: Either, I gave you both - the first line would be if you create it from code, or the others would be for XML. I don't know why this obvious solution attracted an anonymous downvote